# Difference in winding a coil clockwise vs counter clockwise

Tags: electromagnetism

I was watching a YouTube video on the difference of winding a coil clockwise vs winding a coil counter clockwise. It said the poles would be opposite using the same battery configuration. I've been thinking about this and it seems to me the poles would be the same regardless of the direction of the wind. I've included a terrible drawing to help explain my question. Thanks

[image]

Comment: [Biot-Savart Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot–Savart_law)

Answer (score 2):

The following might be useful.  Consider using the "right hand rule" and point your thumb along the wire in the direction of the current going from (+) to (-) and curl your fingers to show the direction of the magnetic field.

In the left hand drawing, your fingers point towards the (-) end inside the coil, and towards the (+) end outside the coil since the magnetic field forms a loop around the wire.

For the right hand drawing, your fingers would point towards the (+) end inside the coil and towards the (-) end on the outside, which is the opposite of the situation in the left hand drawing.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helps very much. I see where the poles would be opposite. Sorry for the silly question but I'm 71 years old, retired and only now have the time to contemplate the mysteries of the universe...laughs